# ¿Cómo guardar datos de login con checkbox y shared preferences?

Tags: java, android

Tengo el siguiente método pero me da error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.widget.CheckBox.isChecked()' on a null object reference
```

Quisiera obtener una indicación y recomendaciones de como realizar este procedimiento correctamente para guardar estos datos en shared preferences
utilizando checkbox

```
btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (saveinfo.isChecked()) {
            chk_remembereditor = login.edit();
            chk_remembereditor.putString(getString(R.string.saved_login_key), String.valueOf(editEmail.getText()));
            chk_remembereditor.putString(getString(R.string.saved_login_password), String.valueOf(editPassword.getText()));
            chk_remembereditor.commit();
            AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
            attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(),"");

        } else {
            AttemptLogin attemptLogin= new AttemptLogin();
            attemptLogin.execute(editName.getText().toString(),editPassword.getText().toString(),"");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: ¿saveinfo es un Checkbox? agrega como lo defines e inicializas

Comment: eror mio, gracias!!

Comment: Estaba definida la variable pero la inicializabas obteniendo la referencia mediante findViewbyId() :-P